# Formula for obtaining position and rotation matrix depending on 3 points in space

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d, projective-geometry

This question is related to [This one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136668/position-a-camera-so-that-lt-corner-is-a-3d-point-and-br-corner-another) in gamedev stackexchange

> I would like to place a camera so that it have a specific portion of space in sight, for that I would like to place it equidistant to 2 point in space corresponding to the wanted left top corner and the wanted right bottom corner and a dandling third point which MUST be projected on the lower left corner but is not required to be equidistant with the others.
>
> Known infomation include:
>
> - Vertical FoV
> - Horizontal FoV
> - Coordinates of the 3 points (A, B and D respectively)
>
> Does anyone have a nice formula that may give me the position and orientation of the camera given that requirement ?

FoV (for field of view) are that the camera "sees" from its position in both positive and negative angle from its rotation.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6jG_sMP3liaMGZjeDE4bDY2NlU/view?usp=sharing) is a drawing of the kind of things I need.

Comment: Vertical FoV & Horizontal FoV are angles ? The points are 3 vectors of course. & you just want a formula for the camera position ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yes, I want a formula for the camera position that would match those requirements